# SVM versus Bayesian regression example(s)?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, svm, hierarchical-bayesian

I am trying to track down examples where some basic problems have been tackled via both classical Machine Learning algorithms and more formal statistical methods.  In particular, I'm interested in examples where SVM has been contrasted with hierarchical Bayesian methods. (but I'll happily take non-SVM examples.)

FWIW- I ran across a blog post that suggested that Bayesian stat methods provided additional insight beyond that provided by SVM, but foolishly didn't bookmark.

Comment: Look into Gaussian process regression as it is often contrasted and compared to SVM.

Comment: +Dan Thanks, that got me started in yet another direction that I had forgotten about.